# How to compare comma separated values and with two different ids-php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

The pictures of person shown are just fake data.
[image]This is my table structure

id   | Author     |    Co-authors

1    | Ronnie    |    vinay, gopal, arun
2    | Razor        |    karthick, webster, ming
3    | Taz             |    earl, karthick, vinay
4    | Baron       |    gopal, arun, sanjeev

Now I want to select two authors say ronnie and baron, so now their co-authors should be compared. In this case the matches would be gopal, arun so the output should gopal and arun.

How to do that in mysql query. Please help.

Comment: You have a lousy table structure.  You should have a table structure with one row per author and the work they have authored.  Then your query would be much simpler to express.

Comment: Yah the co authors also have separate rows with different ids

Comment: . . Then show that table structure.  Also, choose which database you are really using.

Comment: I have attached the screen shot bro, do you got it?

Comment: So if you look at the picture, there are two co-authors matches one is sreeram and one is frank kruzel , so only those two authors must be shown.

Comment: It's mysql or sqlserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a suggested structure for your project. May be it will be an `articles` table in your case instead of `books` or anything else that authors and co-authors are related to. By this way, it will be much easier to do query on your data after :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4431a/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE books
    (`id` int, `title` varchar(5));

INSERT INTO books
    (`id`, `title`)
VALUES
    (1, 'book1'),
    (2, 'book2'),
    (3, 'book3'),
    (4, 'book4');

CREATE TABLE authors
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(8));

INSERT INTO authors
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Ronnie'),
    (2, 'Razor'),
    (3, 'Taz'),
    (4, 'Baron'),
    (5, 'vinay'),
    (6, 'karthick'),
    (7, 'earl'),
    (8, 'gopal'),
    (9, 'webster'),
    (10, 'karthick'),
    (11, 'arun'),
    (12, 'ming'),
    (13, 'sanjeev');

CREATE TABLE type
    (`id` int, `type` varchar(9));

INSERT INTO type
    (`id`, `type`)
VALUES
    (1, 'author'),
    (2, 'co-author');

CREATE TABLE wrote
    (`id` int, `book_id` int, `author_id` int, `type_id` int);

INSERT INTO wrote
    (`id`, `book_id`, `author_id`, `type_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 2, 1),
    (3, 3, 3, 1),
    (4, 4, 4, 1),
    (5, 1, 5, 2),
    (6, 2, 6, 2),
    (7, 3, 7, 2),
    (8, 4, 8, 2),
    (9, 1, 8, 2),
    (10, 2, 9, 2),
    (11, 3, 10, 2),
    (12, 4, 11, 2),
    (13, 1, 11, 2),
    (14, 2, 12, 2),
    (15, 3, 5, 2),
    (16, 4, 13, 2);
```

**This is your actual data :**

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT b.id, a.name as author, group_concat(co.name) as co_authors
FROM books b
INNER JOIN wrote wa ON wa.book_id = b.id AND wa.type_id = 1
INNER JOIN authors a ON wa.author_id = a.id 
INNER JOIN wrote wco ON wco.book_id = b.id AND wco.type_id = 2
INNER JOIN authors co ON wco.author_id = co.id
GROUP BY b.title, a.name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4431a/1/0)**:

```
| ID | AUTHOR |            CO_AUTHORS |
|----|--------|-----------------------|
|  1 | Ronnie |      arun,vinay,gopal |
|  2 |  Razor | webster,ming,karthick |
|  3 |    Taz |   earl,karthick,vinay |
|  4 |  Baron |    sanjeev,gopal,arun |
```

**This is what you are trying to do.**

*Note `AND a.id in (1,4);` where `id 1` is `Ronnie` and `id 4` is `Baron` :*

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT co.name as coauthor
FROM books b
INNER JOIN wrote wa ON wa.book_id = b.id AND wa.type_id = 1
INNER JOIN authors a ON wa.author_id = a.id AND a.id in (1,4)
INNER JOIN wrote wco ON wco.book_id = b.id AND wco.type_id = 2
INNER JOIN authors co ON wco.author_id = co.id 
GROUP BY co.name
HAVING count(co.name) > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4431a/1/1)**:

```
| COAUTHOR |
|----------|
|     arun |
|    gopal |
```

Comment: That is very nice bro, but im using php too, now I am totally confused.

Comment: I am confused with the book table because I don't have that thing and all.

Comment: They have different subject areas

Comment: So instead of `books`, you will have a `subject_areas` table

Comment: Yes bro but the layout is somewhat different

Comment: What is that co.name? What is co actually?

Comment: This is to optimize your db (you added an `optimization`tag at your question). Cause it's not a good practice to have comma delimited list in a field. This is a lack of standardization in your design

Comment: Sorry for the late reply bro, I will check and come back again. Bro one more thing, you are using id IN (1, 4) but if I am using php variable lets say $id then how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

A table called Authors (put all the authors and co-authors in this table)

```
id  |  Author
1   |  Bob
2   |  Jim
3   |  Sally
4   |  Joan
```

Then a table of the relations between authors

```
id  |  authorid  |  coauthorid
1   |  1         |  4
2   |  2         |  3
3   |  1         |  3
```

and so on.  One row for each author/coauthor relationship.

Comment: Could you me a mysql query suggestion for my question

Comment: You would just do a join to get the authors ids from the author table from the coauthorid.  So you would get all of the coauthorids associated with an author, and use that id to get the name from the author table.